# In JavaScript, How to reference the return value of a method from a deeper nested method

Tags: javascript, object, return-value

What is the value of `this` in the two contexts, and how does one nested function reference the other function's returned value?

```
var rootObj = {
    nestedObjA: {
        functionA: function() {
            // what is value of 'this' here?
            return 'foo';
        }
    },
    nestedObjB: {
        functionB: function() {
            // how to reference? >> rootObj.nestedObjA.functionA
            // what is the value of 'this' here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `:` instead of `=`? That's a syntax error.

Comment: Can't you just try it out? `console.log(this);`.

Comment: I'll fix the typo.   I wanted to know `this` as part of the answer just for future reader and completeness sake.

Comment: I think you already answered your question "*how to reference?*": Use `rootObj.nestedObjA.functionA()`. There's no way to access it from `this`, if your method is called on the `nestedObjB`.

Comment: Really?  I thought i did that in my code already and it didn't work.   I'll try again.

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how the function is called. You haven't shown us that.

Comment: @Quentin the greater question I'm asking is How i should call the function.  Specifically, how do I call functionA from within functionB

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: `rootObj.nestedObjB.functionB()`.

Comment: What Quentin means is are you calling/applying it i.e. `fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])`. You can do `rootObj.nestedObjA.functionA.apply(rootObj)` therefore `rootObj.nestedObjB.functionB` is available at `this.nestedObjB.functionB`.

Comment: I'm trying to get foo from within functionB

Comment: @Ben — There's no reference to it there (under normal circumstances at least) other than through the root object.

Comment: @Cakes, way over my head.  No idea what you just said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `this` within both functions should be `rootObj.nestedObjA.functionA` , `rootObj.nestedObjB.functionB`, respectively. To check value of `this` , could add `console.dir(this)` within each function.

To return a value from a function you should add `return` within function body , e.g.; `return rootObj.nestedObjA.functionA()` within`rootObj.nestedObjB.functionB`

```js
var rootObj = {
    nestedObjA: {
        functionA: function() {
            // what is value of 'this' here?
            console.dir(this);
            return 'foo';
        }
    },
    nestedObjB: {
        functionB: function() {
            // how to reference? >> rootObj.nestedObjA.functionA
            // what is the value of 'this' here?
            console.dir(this);
            return rootObj.nestedObjA.functionA()
        }
    }
}

var res = rootObj.nestedObjB.functionB();
console.log(res); // 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranteed answer to "What is the value of `this` inside of a function?", as you can set it with the [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)/[`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) methods of the function prototype.

```
var rootObj = {
  nestedObjA: {
    functionA: function() {
      var foo = "bar";
      return foo;
    }
  },
  nestedObjB: {
    functionB: function() {
      var foo = this.nestedObjA.functionA();
      console.log(foo);
    }
  }
}

// When calling functionB() you could use:
rootObj.nestedObjB.functionB.apply(rootObj);
```

The value of `this` by default is the function scope of `functionB`;